# Herencia en entity framework por jerarquia

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework, herencia

tengo una problema que hace dias no puedo solucionar, estoy trabajando con enttity framework codefirst en vs2015 con c#, tengo una jerarquia,resumiendo:

Persona
-idPersona
-nombre
-apellido

Usuario
-idPersona
-usuario
-password

Operario
-idPersona
-nivel
-cantHoras

Ahora bien, con codefirst al crear las entidades no me crea una herencia, lo que crea es que un Usuario tiene "dentro" una persona, no hace la clase Persona Abstracta.

Como debo definir el modelo? la herencia? las clases para luego hacer un Add-migration y un update-database y funcione la herencia

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas herencia en tus clases EF te crea las tablas enlazadas por FK's, es decir que tendrías:

```
class Persona {
 // String porque asumo que es seguridad social o algo de eso
 public string IdPersona { get; set;}
 public string Nombre { get; set;}
 public string Apellidos { get; set;}
}

class Usuario : Persona {
 public string Password { get; set;}
}

class Operario : Usuario {
 public TimeSpan HorasTrabajadas { get; set;}
}
```

Así cuando creas el `Operario` creas un `Usuario` y una `Persona` cada uno en su tabla.